# Why can't I find my Samum bombs in my inventory?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I tried to destroy a monster nest in *Witcher 3* but it says I didn't have the right bomb.

I tried to craft a Samum bomb and it says I already have it, but I can't find it.
I have read other comments about using a strong alcohol but I can't work out how to do it.

Does anyone have some advice?

Comment: 1x of any strong alcohol is automatically used to refill all bombs and potions you have to the max when you meditate for at least an hour.

Answer (score -1):

Meditate. If you have basic ingredients, your alchemy creations will be refilled.

Comment: I have tried meditating but i get nothing?

Comment: It says i already have the bombs but when i meditate they only regenerate my enhanced samum.

Comment: When i meditate it only regenerated my enhanced samum. I cant find the standard samum bomb that it says i have.

Comment: You can't have samum after you get enhanced samum. Use the enhanced samum instead.